# Shared folder not accessible when running tomcat as a service

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I have issue to access shred folder. Also when i am deploying my war file on tomcat server. Its not using user account. My credentials file are inside user folder.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat configuration folder sharing

For example, the physical folder on the server is: d:\datafile\sharedata

There are files inside: d:\datafile\sharedata\1\test.pdf

Add the following content under  in tomcat/conf/server.xml

Then share the http address of the file after access: http://localhost:8080/sharefile/1/test.pdf

Configured server.xml file

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue i found solution :
 Open Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services. Double click on the Tomcat service. Go to the Log On tab. Select "This account", then fill in your credentials.